# Creating a user account in AD with JNDI and minimum password age

Tags: java, security, active-directory, jndi, user-accounts

So I want to create a user account in Windows 2003 with Active Directory utilizing JNDI. I am following the following example: http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=582103 (first post). The following code is throwing an LDAP error I believe due to a chicken and egg problem of creating a user and then setting a password that is constrained by a minimum password age of 1 day.

```
//Replace the "unicdodePwd" attribute with a new value
//Password must be both Unicode and a quoted string
String newQuotedPassword = "\"Password2000\"";
byte[] newUnicodePassword = newQuotedPassword.getBytes("UTF-16LE");

mods[0] = new ModificationItem(DirContext.REPLACE_ATTRIBUTE, new BasicAttribute("unicodePwd", newUnicodePassword));
mods[1] = new ModificationItem(DirContext.REPLACE_ATTRIBUTE, new BasicAttribute("userAccountControl",Integer.toString(UF_NORMAL_ACCOUNT + UF_PASSWORD_EXPIRED)));

// Perform the update
ctx.modifyAttributes(userName, mods);
System.out.println("Set password & updated userccountControl");
```

I am getting a Ldap Error Code: 53 problem 5003 (unable to perform) when it tries to set the password which I believe is the minimum password age. What is really odd is that if I go into active directory users and computers as the domain admin I can't set the password either. The only way I can get it to change is if I select the reset password' option and then enable the 'user must change account at next logon.' After I set this, then I can set the password both programmatically and through the GUI.

I also tried setting the change password at next logon after the create but before I did the password change in my code but this didn't work either. It did change the box but I still was unable to change the password and got the 5003 error.

Has anyone had any experience using JNDI to create users with a minimum password age on Windows 2003? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I used Java a few months ago to admin an AD server.

It works well, but there is an important thing to know: password is a "protected" attribute in AD:

- it can never be read by the LDAP protocol
- it can be set/updated **only** with a connection secured by SSH.

So, in your Java code, you have to access the AD with a "https://..." adress, and to specify the SSH protocol in your JNDI connection attributes. The procedure is explained here: http://java.sun.com/products/jndi/tutorial/ldap/security/ssl.html

```
// Specify SSL
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PROTOCOL, "ssl");
```

Comment: I am using SSL and it works with existing users. I can also chang ethe password of my created user when I toggle on and off the 'change password at next logon'. So I know it's not SSL issues.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use SSL connection to modify value of unicodePwd attribute

see this link:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc223248.aspx

Windows 2000 operating system servers require that the client have a 128-bit (or better) SSL/TLS-encrypted connection to the DC in order to modify this attribute. On Windows Server 2003 operating system, Windows Server 2008 operating system, Windows Server 2008 R2 operating system, Windows Server 2012 operating system, Windows Server 2012 R2 operating system, and Windows Server 2016 operating system, the DC also permits modification of the unicodePwd attribute on a connection protected by 128-bit (or better) Simple Authentication and Security Layer (SASL)-layer encryption instead of SSL/TLS.